# Is the continuous extension of $\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function $f(x)=\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ can be extended to a continuous function at $0$ by defining $f(0)$ to be $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$.

Clearly, by the quotient rule, $f'(x)=\frac{x \cdot \cos x-\sin x}{x^2}$ for all $x \ne 0$. Is the extended version of $f$ also differentiable at $0$?

Attempt (using L'Hopital's rule together with the product rule):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot \cos x-\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x-x \cdot \sin x-\cos x}{2x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\sin x}{2}=0$$

So, does that mean that $f'(0)=0$ (and $f'$ is continuous at $0$)?

Comment: Have a look at the Taylor series.

Comment: Instead of computing the limit of the derivatives, you can just compute the derivative at the point itself. $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)/h - 1}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)-h}{h^2}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos(h)-1}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-\sin(h)}{2}=0$.

Comment: Your argument has proven that the limit of $f'$ exists at zero. This is not yet what you aim to prove, which is that $f'$ is defined at $0$. However, you could use it to get there. One way is to use Lagrange's theorem to verify that $f'(0)$ exists, from this information. We have that $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)/h-1}{h}$. By Lagrange's theorem, there is $x_h\in(0,h)$ such that $\frac{\sin(h)/h-1}{h}=f'(x_h)$. Therefore, the limit above is equal to $\lim_{h\to0}f'(x_h)$. Since $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)=0$ exists and $x_h\to0$ as $h\to0$, then $f'(0)$ exists too and is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; actually, you can just divide through in the Maclaurin series of $\sin$ term by term to get $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$ for $x \neq 0$ (and the continuous extension agrees with this series everywhere). This reveals all the derivatives at zero, and in particular that the first derivative at zero is zero.